# When indexed, throw Exception during add Vertex

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

The index has built well;
No Exception Here, and the graphManagement has committed well;

```
graphManagement.buildIndex("uidIndex", Vertex.class). 
     addKey(graphManagement.getPropertyKey("uid_code")).
     buildCompositeIndex();
```

i have configured the **query.force-index=true** ；
But when I try to add some vertex, using the propertyKey 'uid_code', 
code is following:

```
Vertex vertex = g.V().addV(label).
       property(propertyKey, propertyValue).
       next();
```

Exception throwed :

```
org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphException: Could not find a suitable index to answer graph query and graph scans are disabled: [()]:VERTEX
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx$6.execute(StandardJanusGraphTx.java:1283)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx$6.execute(StandardJanusGraphTx.java:1150)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.QueryProcessor$LimitAdjustingIterator.getNewIterator(QueryProcessor.java:209)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.LimitAdjustingIterator.hasNext(LimitAdjustingIterator.java:68)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$7.computeNext(Iterators.java:650)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.ResultSetIterator.nextInternal(ResultSetIterator.java:54)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.ResultSetIterator.<init>(ResultSetIterator.java:44)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.QueryProcessor.iterator(QueryProcessor.java:68)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterables$7.iterator(Iterables.java:613)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.optimize.JanusGraphStep.lambda$new$0(JanusGraphStep.java:71)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.GraphStep.processNextStart(GraphStep.java:142)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:143)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.ExpandableStepIterator.next(ExpandableStepIterator.java:50)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.MapStep.processNextStart(MapStep.java:36)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.next(AbstractStep.java:128)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.next(AbstractStep.java:38)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.util.DefaultTraversal.next(DefaultTraversal.java:200)
    at dataTrans.KfkMsgParser.createMerge(KfkMsgParser.java:742)
```

**Can someone tell me whether i forget something in document ?

Or

 what i can do to fix this problem ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a single vertex, you should invoke `addV()` directly on the traversal source `g`:

```
 String propertyKey = "uid_code";
 Vertex vertex = g.addV(label).
     property(propertyKey, propertyValue).
     next();
```

When you start the query with `g.V().addV(label)...`, the traversal attempts to scan all vertices with `g.V()` and thus the exception is thrown.

Comment: Hi, I am happy to see u answer ! I have read the JanusGraph  janusgraph/janusgraph-examples/example-common code for several times. When building index, it seems different with the doc which doesn't has the awaitGraphIndexStatus part ! so I wonder what is the difference 
 and whether awaitGraphIndexStatus  is necessary ?

Comment: If you define the index before inserting any data (best practice), the index becomes enabled immediately, so there is no need to reindex or force any index status changes.

Answer (score 2):

Your index should be enabled to be used.

```
graph.tx().rollback(); //Never create new indexes while a transaction is active
JanusGraphManagement graphManagement = graph.openManagement();
graphManagement.buildIndex("uidIndex", Vertex.class). 
     addKey(graphManagement.getPropertyKey("uid_code")).
     buildCompositeIndex();
graphManagement.commit();

//Wait for the index to become available
ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, "uidIndex").call();

graphManagement = graph.openManagement();
// Use REINDEX to reindex old data and enable the index
// Use ENABLE to simply enable the index
graphManagement.updateIndex(graphManagement.getGraphIndex("uidIndex"), SchemaAction.REINDEX).get();
graphManagement.commit();
```

You can check index lifecycle here: https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/wiki/Indexing

Here is the index documentation:
https://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/indexes.html

Comment: you are right, many thanks!! I think i have never considered the reindex step.... - -!